# Getting started creating an online Drag-n-Drop designer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I'm tasked with creating a drag-m-drop label designer and I pretty much have no idea how to actually do this.

At the moment it pretty much looks like this, still static, but it gives an idea what I'm going for.
[image: screenshot of designer so far]
People need to be able to drag the icons on the right onto the blank label (the white and green area). On drag a new instance of what object the icon represents, usually an image or a text, is to be created and I need to save the drop location and size of the instance, with the blank label image as the bounds of the drawing area.

At the moment the image is just an  tag and the icons are defined as  tags, though that'll probably have to change I presume.

So what techniques are usable for this kind of functionality? I've heard SVG might do the trick, though I'm not sure if it supports images (from a sprite image?) as it's objects.
I have no experience making this sort of thing, so any tips and guidance are welcome.

And Here's the HTML of what's shown in the screenshot (generated from an ASP.NET MVC View)

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="row designerBox">
    <div class="col-md-10 designerCanvas">
        <img class="col-md-12 blankLabel" id="imgLabel" src="/images/Temp/temp.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 designerControlBox">
        <h3 class="col-md-12">Controls</h3>
        <span title="Hazard Icon" class="col-md-4 designerControl hazardIcon"></span>
        <span title="Product Info" class="col-md-4 designerControl info"></span>
        <span title="Product Name" class="col-md-4 designerControl prodName"></span>
        <span title="Color Info 1" class="col-md-4 designerControl color1"></span>
        <span title="Color Info 2" class="col-md-4 designerControl color2"></span>
        <span title="Mix Icons" class="col-md-4 designerControl mixIcon"></span>
        <span title="Usage Icons" class="col-md-4 designerControl useIcon"></span>
        <span title="Batch Number" class="col-md-4 designerControl batch"></span>
        <span title="Production Date" class="col-md-4 designerControl prodDate"></span>
        <span title="VOC" class="col-md-4 designerControl voc"></span>
        <span title="Content" class="col-md-4 designerControl content"></span>
        <span title="Bar Code" class="col-md-4 designerControl barcode"></span>
        <span title="Address" class="col-md-4 designerControl address"></span>
        <span title="Phone" class="col-md-4 designerControl phone"></span>
        <span title="Fax" class="col-md-4 designerControl fax"></span>
        <span title="Email address" class="col-md-4 designerControl email"></span>
        <span title="Site" class="col-md-4 designerControl website"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="Width">Width</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input name="Width" class="form-control" id="Width" style="width: 50px; display: inline-block;" type="number" value="0" data-val-required="Please enter the Width." data-val="true"> mm
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="Heigth">Heigth</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input name="Heigth" class="form-control" id="Heigth" style="width: 50px; display: inline-block;" type="number" value="0" data-val-required="Please enter the Heigth." data-val="true"> mm
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Name">Label Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input name="Name" class="form-control" id="Name" type="text" value="" data-val-required="Please enter the Label Name." data-val="true">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="control-label col-md-12">Can be used for containers from <input class="form-control" style="width: 50px; display: inline-block;" asp-for="Name"> till <input class="form-control" style="width: 50px; display: inline-block;" asp-for="Name"> liter.</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Name"></span> 
        <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Width"></span>
        <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Heigth"></span>
        <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="MinVolume"></span>
        <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="MaxVolume"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

So I almost got it working the way I wanted, for now with just the 1st icon (the red diamond). I can now drag that icon on the svg I added, I can selected (and multiple with shift or ctrl), resize it with +/- and move it with the Arrow keys. On IE, I can also move the placed icon by dragging it again, though for some reason the latter doesn't work in chrome :(

FF doesn't even support dropping the icon on the svg at all.

The  imgLabel is edited a bit and is now joined by a SVG container:

```
<div class="col-md-10 designerCanvasContainer">
    <img id="imgLabel" src="/images/Temp/temp.png" class="col-md-12 blankLabel" />
    <svg id="svgLabel" class="col-md-12 designerCanvas" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></svg>
</div>
```

The relevant css vor these objects is the followed:

```
.designerCanvasContainer {
    background-color: white;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}

.designerCanvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.blankLabel {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: white;
}
```

The containing div and img need to be positioned relatively (so the div resizes with the image) and the svg needs to be absolute and snapped to the edges of the div, so it's placed over the image.

Off course I added a drag event to the icon as well, the getOffset function is to determie where on the icon the cursor is, or it'll draw the dropped icon with the cursor a 0,0 of the icon, moving it out of place:

```
<span draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" onmousedown="getOffset(event)" class="col-md-4 designerControl hazardIcon" title="Hazard Icon" />
```

And needless to say everything is touched up withh some js magic:

```
var xOffset = 0;
var yOffset = 0;
var xOld = 0;
var yOld = 0;
var hazardDrag = new Image();
var id;
$(document).ready(function () {
    hazardDrag.src = '/images/dragHazardIcon.png'; 
    //Part of setdragimage-ie.js to support event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, x, y) in IE
    //Function will preload the custom drag image.
    setDragImageIEPreload(hazardDrag);
});

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.key !== "Shift" && $(".selected").length)
    {
        //Only when we have selected SVG objects we have use for the key actions
        //The e.preventDefault() are to prevent the default actions of the key
        //(e.g.scrolling with the arrows or going back to the previous page with backspace)
        switch (e.key)
        {
            case "ArrowUp":
            case "Up": {
                move(0, -1);
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
            }
            case "ArrowDown":
            case "Down": {
                move(0, 1);
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
            }
            case "ArrowLeft":
            case "Left": {
                move(-1, 0);
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
            }
            case "ArrowRight":
            case "Right": {
                move(1, 0);
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
            }
            case "Subtract":
            case "-": {
                resize(-1);
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
            }
            case "Add":
            case "+": {
                resize(1);
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
            }
            case "Del":
            case "Delete":
            case "Backspace": {
                $(".selected").each(function (i) {
                    $("#" + this.id + "-border").remove();
                });
                $(".selected").remove();
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
            }
            case "Enter": {
                $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
            }
        }
        //Always update the selection frames so they don't get left behind.
        drawSelectBoxes();
    }
});


//All dropped icons will have a svg class attached to it.
//This function will provide (de)select functionality to those objects.
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    var id = "#" + e.target.id;
    if (id !== "#" && $(id).hasClass("svg")) {
        if (!e.ctrlKey && !e.shiftKey) {
            $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
            $(id).addClass("selected");
        }
        else if ($(id).hasClass("selected"))
            $(id).removeClass("selected");
        else
            $(id).addClass("selected");
    }
    else
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    drawSelectBoxes();
});

//Small function to execute the keyboard move
function move(x, y) {
    $(".selected").each(function (i) {
        $(this).attr("x", (parseFloat($(this).attr("x")) + x));
        $(this).attr("y", (parseFloat($(this).attr("y")) + y));
    });
}

//Small function to execute the +/- resizes
function resize(by) {
    $(".selected").each(function (i) {
        $(this).attr("height", (parseFloat($(this).attr("height")) + by));
        $(this).attr("width", (parseFloat($(this).attr("width")) + by));
    });
}

//Turns of default drop behaviour on svg container
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

//Gets the current cursor coordinates, using this to nove a svg object
function getCoord(ev) {
    xOld = ev.x;
    yOld = ev.y;
}

//As svg objects do not support css borders, I'm using svg rectangle to draw a border 
//around a selected svg object.
function drawSelectBoxes()
{
    $(".svg").each(function (x) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            if (!$("#" + this.id + "-border").length) {
                var border = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');
                border.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', $(this).attr('height'));
                border.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', $(this).attr('width'));
                border.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', $(this).attr('x'));
                border.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', $(this).attr('y'));
                border.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', '#cccccc');
                border.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'none');
                border.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', this.id + "-border");
                $("#svgLabel").append(border);
            }
            else {
                var border = "#" + this.id + "-border";
                $(border).attr('height', $(this).attr('height'));
                $(border).attr('width', $(this).attr('width'));
                $(border).attr('x', $(this).attr('x'));
                $(border).attr('y', $(this).attr('y'));
            }
        }
        else
            $("#" + this.id + "-border").remove();
    });
}

//Get's the offset of the cursor towards the start of an icon you're dragging.
//We'll use this offset to draw the svg object at the correct location.
//If we don't do this the cursor will be the 0,0 coordinate of the dropped image and 
//it'll move compared to the shown drag image.
function getOffset(ev) {
    xOffset = ev.offsetX;
    yOffset = ev.offsetY;
    $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    drawSelectBoxes();
}

//The drag event, it sets the correct parameters so the drop event will work accordingly.
//I'm using the "text" data variable cause the original icon, and thus it's class names, 
//is not available in the drop event when droping the external icons.
function drag(ev) {
    var img;
    if ($(ev.target).hasClass("hazardIcon")) {
        img = hazardDrag;
        ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, xOffset, yOffset);
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", "hazard");
    }
    else if ($(ev.target).hasClass("svg")) {
        id = "#" + ev.target.id;
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", "svg");
    }
}

//The drop event set on the svg container.
//It'll create a new svg object when a new icon is dropped on the container
//or update the x/y of an existing svg object when that is dragged.
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var svg;
    if (ev.target.id === "svgLabel")
        svg = ev.target;
    else
        svg = ev.target.parentNode;
    var type = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    if (type != "svg")
    {
        var mxy = svg.createSVGPoint();
        mxy.x = ev.clientX;
        mxy.y = ev.clientY;
        pos = mxy.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
    }
    switch (type) {
        case "hazard": {
            //Here we'll create a new svg <image> for our hazad icon.
            //We can't use a standard jquery append() as it'll translate the <image> 
            //to <img> and this is not a valid svg object.
            var img = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'image');
            img.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '50');
            img.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '50');
            img.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', '' + hazardDrag.src + '');
            img.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', '' + pos.x - xOffset + '');
            img.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', '' + pos.y - yOffset + '');
            img.setAttributeNS(null, 'draggable', 'true');
            img.setAttributeNS(null, 'ondragstart', "drag(event)");
            img.setAttributeNS(null, 'onmousedown', "getCoord(event)");
            img.setAttributeNS(null, 'visibility', 'visible');
            img.setAttributeNS(null, 'class', 'svg');
            img.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'hazard-' + parseInt(pos.x) + '-' + parseInt(pos.y));
            $("#svgLabel").append(img);
            break;
        }
        case "svg": {
            //Svg objects just have their coordinated updated.
            $(id).attr("x", (parseFloat($(id).attr("x")) + (ev.x - xOld)));
            $(id).attr("y", (parseFloat($(id).attr("y")) + (ev.y - yOld)));
        }
    }
    drawSelectBoxes();
}
```

So this is the designer so far, if someone has any idea on how to get it fully functional in Chrome and FF, I'd be very gratefull.
Client is fine with just IE, companies you know, but I want to at least have it functional in the 3 biggest browsers.

In short Chrome is still missing dragging of the svg objects and FF can't drop on the svg container, the drop event doesn't get triggered at all.

UPDATE 2

So moving the drop and dragover events to the surrounding div instead of the svg container, FF works like Chrome before, the other 2 browsers have no changes. The drop function wasn't impacted as the resulting target is still the svg container.
All that's needed now is being able to move the svg objects with the mouse in Chrome and FF.

Edited HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-10 designerCanvasContainer" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="imgLabel" src="/images/Temp/temp.png" class="col-md-12 blankLabel" />
    <svg id="svgLabel" class="col-md-12 designerCanvas"></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: You should take a look at the `draggable` attribute. https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_global_draggable.asp would be a good place to start. I suppose you can figure it out from there :).

Comment: That gives like basic drag and drop functionalities to the objects, seems the WC3s does give an example that can get me to instantiate a new object through  jQuery or so, but the hard part after that is nowing where on the image, like coordinates, the object is dropped. The objects should also be resizable.

Comment: Draggable works good for webshops and things like that. For generating labels I wouldn't recommend using it. Using sprite images might also be a bad idea for this project. I'm just starting out in svg myself, but I think this could be done with svg. It will be quite a fun / challenging project tough ;).

Comment: So basically in short I have to instantiate a SVG object when I drag one of the icon spans, make sure those new objects are draggable as well and write a js that edits their coordinates on drag.

You're right about not using sprites for the SVG images, don't think you can scale those.

I'll post a working example once I cracked this puzzle :)

Comment: I use jquery.ui.position.js for that (https://jqueryui.com/position/). You can easily implement an ondrag event to write the coordinates to like data-x and data-y attributes. I have a full document cover designer that does just that.